# Adding a space to a formula

Tags: excel

Good day,
I'm using the following formula to alter a list of first/last names.  The result of the formula works well for me except I would like a space between the first name and the initial of the last name.  How can I add the space into my existing formula?

```
=RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A5,", "," * ",LEN(A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")))))& LEFT(A5)&"."
```

Names initially entered in my spreadsheet:

```
Doe, John
Doe, Jane
```

Result of formula entered:
JohnD.
JaneD.

This is how I would like to see the names appear in my spreadsheet:

```
John D.
Jane D.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you have )& LEFT  adjust to )&" "& LEFT

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
=RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A5,", "," * ",LEN(A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A5," ","")))))& " " & LEFT(A5)&"."
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help!  Feel free to mark the answer as accepted and / or up vote it so that other users with a similar question know that the answer was helpful.  Either way, best of luck with the rest of your project!